# How to render html in C++ app using already installed firefox or chrome

Tags: c++, windows, firefox, google-chrome

We have a requirement to render a local html file in a webview on a mfc window. Currently we have achieved this with IE and now we need to do the same with firefox and then with chrome.

Some of the options suggest using webkit or gecko sdk but we would rather like to use already installed libraries and binaries of these browsers on a windows machine.

It would be of great help if you could point me into some documentation or some sample code to achieve this.

Thanks for your response.
-Aditya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE provides a COM component but AFAIK none of the other browsers do.

Answer (score 0):

Qt provide QtWebView class, it's a wrapper of WebKit's web view, and it's cross-platform.
Or use MFC/WTL's CHtmlView, but IE so sucks.